# Set Variable with Unknown type

Tags: java

I want to do the following. The two classes had the same methods. Is there a way to setting the variable without knowing the Type?

```
public class Example {
    private variable;

    public Example(SampleClassOne var) {
        variable = var;
    }

    public Example(SampleClassTwo var) {
        variable = var;
    }
}
```

Comment: If they have same methods then it is worth making them implement same interface with those methods. This way you can set variable type to `YourInterface variable`.

Comment: If your two classes extend the same parent or implement the same interface, then it can be done.

Comment: Yes. Its type simply needs to be one of the ancestor types of both classes. Preferrably a common interface (since they have common methods), or java.lang.Object, which is a common superclass of all classes.

Comment: And if types do not implement any common interfaces (but still have methods with common names and behavior) and you can't change types themselves, you can make a delegating wrappers for both types, and those wrappers can implement the common interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this, casting your variable to Object

```
public class Example
{
   private Object variable;

   public Example( Object var )
   {
       variable = var;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there any relation between SampleClassOne & SampleClassTwo?
Are they based on each other? Do they share an interface?
If so you could use that as the type.

Answer (score 0):

Generics exist to address this use case:

```
public class Example<T> {
    T variable;
    public Example(T var) {
        variable = var;
    }
}
```

...but in order to use it, you still have to know what it actually is when casting it. Type erasure will treat that like an `Object`.

Answer (score -1):

Some Notes:

1. Java is not JavaScript.
   Java is a statically typed language
   (use google search to find the definition of statically typed language as needed).
2. This is a super basic question.
   You should spend some time reading the [Oracle Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

If `SampleClassOne` and `SampleClassTwo` have a common ancestor,
make the type of the `private variable` the common ancestor.
All classes always have a common ancestor of `Object`,
but you could use an `Interface` if both classes implement the same interface.

You have not addressed the problem of retrieving the `private variable` value.
I assume that this is not something that you plan to implement
(i.e. there will be no `getVaiable()`) method.

Here is an example:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    ... stuff.
}

public class SampleClassOne
implements
    MyInterface
{
    ... stuff.
}

public class SampleClassTwo
implements
    MyInterface
{
    ... stuff.
}

public class Example
{
    private MyInterface variable;

    // only one constructor required.
    public Example(final MyInterface variableValue)
    {
        variable = variableValue;
    }
}
```